# SQL Create Column Headers by Month ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

I am trying to extract itemised sales data for the past 12 months and build a dynamic table with column headers for each month ID. Extracting the data as below works, however when I get to the point of creating a SUM column for each month ID, I get stuck. I have tried to find similar questions but I'm not sure of the best approach.

```
Select Item, Qty, format(Transaction Date,'MMM-yy')
from Transactions
```

Data Extract:

| Item | Qty | Month ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 50 | Apr-22 |
| A123 | 30 | May-22 |
| A123 | 50 | Jun-22 |
| A321 | 50 | Apr-22 |
| A999 | 25 | May-22 |
| A321 | 10 | Jun-22 |

Desired Output:

| Item | Apr-22 | May-22 | Jun-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 50 | 30 | 50 |
| A321 | 50 | Null | 10 |
| A999 | Null | 25 | Null |

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of pivot operation, where you

- first filter every value according to your "*Month_ID*" value
- then aggregate on common "*Item*"

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Item, Qty, FORMAT(Transaction Date,'MMM-yy') AS Month_ID
    FROM Transactions
)
SELECT Item, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Month_ID = 'Apr-22' THEN Qty END) AS [Apr-22],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Month_ID = 'May-22' THEN Qty END) AS [May-22],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Month_ID = 'Jun-22' THEN Qty END) AS [Jun-22]
FROM cte
GROUP BY Item
```

Note: you don't need the `SUM` as long as there's only one value for each couple <"*Item*", "*Month-Year*">.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the quick and clear answer!

Comment: A slight note that `FORMAT` is *notoriously* slow. `CONVERT` with a little string manipulation (such as `STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(11),GETDATE(),100),4,6,'-')`) would likely be far more performant. Also `Transaction Date` would need delimit identifying, due to the space in the object name (I realise the same syntax error appears in the OP's attempt).